# Python property setting does not assign the right instance attributes (leading underscores) when assigning via __setattr__

Tags: python

I can't set the right properties of an instance when setting their attributes via `setattr` in a factory method.

Given the following code where `data` is a simple dict containing e.g. `{ "age": "64", ...}`

```
def factory(data):
    obj = MyClass()
    for k, v in data.items():
        setattr(obj, k, v)
    return obj

class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self._age = None
        # more...


    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        some_validation(value)
        self._age = value


    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.__dict__.get(item, None)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        self.__dict__[item] = None
        return None

    def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)


c = factory(data)
print(c)
```

I always get the following output when printing the created object:

```
{"_age": "64", ...}
```

But I need to have

```
{"age": "64", ...}
```

Why does the `setattr` method assign the leading underscore?

Comment: ...because your `age.setter` sets `_age`

Comment: What is the data you pass to factory? Provide more code please as somethings do not match, by example when you print your object, it prints a dict?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon it's a dictionary, e.g. `{ "age": "64", ...}`

Comment: @OlivierMelançon added `__str__` method and input data example

Comment: @kindall if I set it to `self.age = value` in the setter I get a `RecursionError`

Comment: Yes, don't set `self.age` in the setter. In any case, your question is about why it's `_age` and not `age` in the instance dict. It's because you don't set an `age` attribute on the instance. You can't because of the setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the things you are trying to achieve get mixed up, like wanting to print `__dict__` for a readable representation, but using private attributes for properties. Let's start from scratch and see how we can implement your class correctly.

You are trying to implement a class which attributes can be accessed both as keys and attributes. That is fine and can be accomplished in a more concise way.

```
class MyClass:
    ...

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.__getattribute__(item)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        return self.__setattr__(key, value)
```

You also want `None` to be returned when an attribute does not exist. This is covered by `__getattr__` which is called exactly when an attribute does not exist.

```
    def __getattr__(self, _):
        return None
```

Then you want to add some validation to some attributes with `property`. It is indeed the correct way to proceed.

```
    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        # some validation here
        self._age = value
```

And finally you want to be able to have a nice string representation of your instance. We have to be careful for that since we had to add some private attributes that we do not want to print.

What we are going to do is implement a method `keys` to allow casting to `dict`. This method will only return keys for attributes which are not private nor methods.

```
    def keys(self):
        return [k for k in dir(self) if not k.startswith('_') and not callable(self[k])]

    def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps(dict(self))
```

This does the right thing.

```
obj = MyClass()

obj.age = 3

print(obj)
# prints: {"age": 3}
```